# python-igraph create graph from file

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I am trying to create a graph from a network stored in a file using the Graph.Read_Edgelist method. I have the following code:

```
netFile = open("trades-train.txt",'r')
graph = Graph.Read_Edgelist(netFile, directed=True)
```

And I receive the following error:

```
igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at src\foreign.c:105: parsing edgelist file failed, Parse error
```

And this is a sample of what I have in the file:

```
7047,1481
1163,1309
6279,2975
2975,6279
```

Which is basically a list of edges of my network. Any idea why I get this error?

I can not find any extra character of things like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace "," with white space. Apparently Graph.Read_Edgelist only understands " " as delimiter for the file.